# How to add service in Angular 2 getting error while injecting?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I added one service in my demo project .

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
    todos = [];
}
```

and injecting this in my component .

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {TodoService} from "./todo-service";

@Component({
    selector :'todo-input',
    template: '<div><button (click)="btnClick(in)">Add item</button><input type="text" #in/></div>'
})

export class Todo {
    constructor(public todoservice: TodoService) {

    }

    btnClick(val) {
        this.todoservice.todos.push(val.value);
        console.log(this.todoservice.todos);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error

```
or: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Todo: (?).
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14388:21)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.get
```

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/bYsvcXFsr1ZPX85JUVPk?p=preview

Comment: Have you declared TodoService in the providers of your NgModule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `app/todo-service.js` file to `app/todo-service.`**t**`s`

And then add it to `providers` list of your component or module:

```
import {TodoService} from "./todo-service";

@Component({
    selector :'todo-input',
    providers: [TodoService], <== this line
    template: '..'
})

export class Todo {
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t9jSh882620MuEhct7Mz?p=preview)**